# Unable to revert changes in P4

Tags: perforce, p4v, p4api.net

I am trying to revert files in a change list with -a and -c option. I did manually like this.

```
p4 revert -c 19264444 file ...
pause
p4 edit -c 19264444 GP*.*
pause
robocopy %SRC% %DEST% *.rom
pause
p4 revert -a 19264444 file ...
```

Trying using p4api.net

Also while opening particular files for edit at a given workspace location like this. Not sure whether format will be accepted appended in the destination path.

```
 //Function for Edit changelist

 public void EditChangeList(Changelist cl, string fileFormat, string   destinationPath)
    {
        var rep = Connect();
        var fs = new FileSpec(new DepotPath(destinationPath + "/" + fileFormat + "/..."));
        var ls= rep.Connection.Client.EditFiles(new Options(EditFilesCmdFlags.None, cl.Id, null), fs);
    }

 // call of above function
  p4.EditChangeList(changelist, gp*.*", destinationPath);
```

Also i couldn't find how to revert files in change list using p4api.net. Could some one guide on this?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Whether you can use both -a and -c in the same 'p4 revert' command? How to run 'edit' from p4api.net? How to run 'revert' from p4api.net? Something else entirely?

Comment: @BryanPendleton. Yes correct. i want to know how i can revert files in a changelist in p4api.net

Comment: Also how i can open files (of particular format say gp*.*) for edit at given location in a changelist using p4api.net

Comment: Also i dont want to use -a and -c in one p4 revert. I want to use it independently.  I want to know how i can revert files in a changelist with -a and - c parameters independently using p4api.net. Also how i can open files for edit using p4api.net

Comment: Here's the doc for the Client.RevertFiles method: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/M_Perforce_P4_Client_RevertFiles.htm

Comment: Yeah, i checked it but i didn't get any example. Could you provide example to revert files in a change list.

Comment: public IList<FileSpec> RevertFiles(
 IList<FileSpec> Files,
 Options options
)  how i can specify change list in this function

Comment: To specify the -c changelist option, you'll do something like: Options opts = new Options();
opts["-c"] = _changelistToRevert.ToString();  Then those will be the options that you'll pass to Client.RevertFiles. You should set up a test server so you can try these API calls out yourself on your test platform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah i did similar to what you mentioned.

Comment: `                var rep = Connect();
                var opts = new Options(ChangeCmdFlags.None, ChangeListType.None);
                opts["-a"] = clNumber;
                //  var fs = new FileSpec(new DepotPath(destinationPath + "/..." + fileFormat));
                IList<FileSpec> revertedFiles = rep.Connection.Client.RevertFiles(null, opts);`